# How to disable the page title output of main content?

Tags: 8

I want to output the page title in the 'title' block and **not** with the main content output. I'm using the Bootstrap theme for Drupal 8.

I've enabled the title block and placed it in its own region but now I've got two page titles being displayed.

I've spent two days and have tried everything to disable the title that is output with   {{ page.content }} in the page.html.twig template.

I do not want to hide it via CSS.

Can the page.content title be disabled?

Comment: Are you sure the page title in the region Content isn't a block too? Out of the box it is.Then you could simply move the block instead of creating a second instance.

Answer (score 1):

The title is probably listed in the content type's manage display list.

Edit the content type and hide the title field.